# App Engine: Empty referrer error from cron Job when calling Endpoint with restricted API key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an App engine app + Cloud endpoints. I have configured a cron task  in the task queue to call one of the endpoints. The cron has an auth-constraint to admin.

All of this is working, however when I restrict the api key to certain domains, I get the following error when the cron is run:

Failed
check_errors {
  code: REFERER_BLOCKED
  detail: "Requests from referer <empty> are blocked."
}

It doesn't seem like I can add a referee header to the cron.yaml

apparently Google App Engine issues cron requests from the IP address 0.1.0.1.

so I could potentially allow that ip, but I want to restrict api key by domain not i.p. and it doesn't seem like I can do both

Does anyone know a workaround to allow the cron job access to an api key restricted by domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this:

Note: I see people referencing this in the docs:

"Calling Google Cloud Endpoints

You cannot call a Google Cloud Endpoint from a cron job. Instead, you should issue a request to a target that is served by a handler that's specified in your app's configuration file or in a dispatch file. That handler then calls the appropriate endpoint class and method."

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron#

Without further explanation or example that I could see.

I am however able to call my endpoints from a cron job, and it was working fine, other than the api key restraint issue.

I read several comments on other posts that mention doing a servlet mapping, but without providing an example, so here is the workaround I found and example code for the servlet mapping.

Java Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
    // call your Endpoint Method here, or whatever you want
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cronServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cronServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cronServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>cronServletConstraint</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/cronServlet</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: myCron
  url: /cronServlet
  schedule: every 12 hours
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-requests-are-handled